# A bug with tags/code parser

Tags: support, code-formatting, code, list

I wanted to add a list and some code:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575311/ios-save-state-when-user-exits-an-application/18589147#18589147)

the list sometimes becomes bold on editing, but I wrote it correctly. I don't know what to do with code at all because its parser doesn't work properly

Comment: Code in a list needs to be indented 8 spaces. Fixed for you.

Comment: thanks. Some days before it had required 4 spaces only

Comment: If so, I can't recall when. It's been 8 spaces in lists for years now (from the start, IIRC).